# Returning html progressively in AppEngine using nodejs/express

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I'd like to return html progressively, so the browser can load dependencies and start rendering above the fold while the server is still generating the html for below the fold.  It takes a few seconds to generate the whole page so it would be a better UX to start seeing results sooner.

In nodejs, I'm using res.writeHead, several res.write's, and then res.end.  This works perfectly when running locally, but when deployed to app-engine (standard) the browser doesn't seem to get anything until the whole page is ready.  Is there a way to return the top of the page earlier when hosted on app-engine?

Sample code

```
app.get('/testprogressiverendering', function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html',
        'Cache-control': 'max-age=0, no-cache'
    });
    var counter = 0;
    var i = setInterval(function () {
        if (counter++ < 3) {
            res.write(`<h2>${counter}</h2>\n`);
        }
        else {
            clearInterval(i);
            res.end('<h2>Done</h2>');
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe the above is possible 'cos per [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/how-requests-are-handled?tab=node.js#streaming_responses)

> App Engine **does not support streaming responses** where data is sent in incremental chunks to the client while a request is being processed. All data from your code is collected as described above and sent as a single HTTP response.